# I have a column full of objects and want to add the attributes of the objects as the column index and their values indexed with the time index

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have currently pulled some historical data from Oanda and created a dataframe in this format.

I then used `df.set_index('time')` to make the time column into the index of the dataframe. However, I am now stuck at with this dataframe.

the `"o","h","l","c"` represents the candle opening, high, low and closing prices.

```
data = [
{'time': '2020-04-02T11:00:00','mid': { 'o': '1.09202', 'h': '1.09293', 'l' : '1.01282', 'c' : '1.09136'}},
{'time': '2020-04-02T12:00:00','mid': { 'o': '1.02102', 'h': '1.02193', 'l' : '1.01282', 'c' : '1.09136'}}]
```

This is where I am stuck at now. I have a column full of objects and want to add the attributes of the objects as the column index and their values indexed with the time index

```
    time                            |  mid 
0| 2020-04-02T11:00:00.000000000Z   | {'o': '1.09202', 'h': '1.09293', 'l': '1.01282', 'c' : '1.09136'}
1| 2020-04-02T12:00:00.000000000Z   | {'o': '1.02102', 'h': '1.02193', 'l': '1.01282', 'c' : '1.09136'}
```

How do I get it to the format below?

```
 time                          | o      | h       | l       | c 
2020-04-02T11:00:00.000000000Z | 1.09202 | 1.09293 | 1.01282 | 1.09136 
2020-04-02T12:00:00.000000000Z | 1.02102 | 1.02193 | 1.01282 | 1.09136
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Edit your answer and include some sample data.

Comment: Sorry, first time using stack overflow. Just edited my question! thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['2020-04-02T', {'o': '1.09202', 'h': '1.09293', 'l': '1.09082', 'c': '1.09323'}]
    ], columns=['time', 'mid']
)
print(df)

          time                                                mid
0  2020-04-02T  {'o': '1.09202', 'h': '1.09293', 'l': '1.09082...
```

---

Now all you need to do is:

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(list(df.mid))], axis=1)
del df['mid']
```

and the keys of the dictionary will become columns in the dataframe:

```
print(df)
          time        o        h        l        c
0  2020-04-02T  1.09202  1.09293  1.09082  1.09323
```